# Are wild figs kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bugs

Here in Eretz Israel, many figs have wasp larvae on them. Are wild figs kosher? Or kosher if you inspect them? I find it hard to believe that one of the shivat haminim is treif.

Comment: Don't all figs have wasps in them? That's how the fruit grows. It's symbiotic.

Comment: My understanding is that a wasp that ends up in the fruit fig (the female plant) ends up dying and being essentially digested by the fig. The larvae grow in the male caprifigs, which are not eaten.

Comment: I think you may have to edit your question to include some scientific info - or at least a link to something. As I understand it, now, how is this question any different from the standard requirement to check just about any produce for bugs before eating them? My neighbor grows a fig tree, and much of it is in my property (AFAIK, halachically, I can eat those in my property, but that's a different discussion.) I just took some off, yesterday, rinsed them and inspected them before consuming. My taste buds were dancing!

Comment: @DanF https://www.esa.org/esablog/research/the-story-of-the-fig-and-its-wasp/ "The commercially cultivated fig tree ... and does not need pollination to produce fruit..." But wild figs do.

Comment: @DanF  "How is this question any different from the standard requirement  to check just about any produce for bugs before eating them?" Not too different. But if *all* wild figs have wasps in them, perhaps that changes the considerations.

Comment: It might. I think the rule regarding whether one can eat certain produce deals with a more "objective" opinion on whether one can eliminate bugs via standard "manual" processes. Many people won't eat broccoli florets or strawberries b/c they feel that nothing would be able to eliminate all the bugs. However, many people still will eat these items as they feel that normal inspection and standard cleaning is sufficient.

Comment: @Double Some figs are parthenocarpic and don't need the wasps.

Comment: @user6591 ragusea fan?

Comment: @Double You just made me so happy:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild (fresh) figs are kosher of course but the insects on them are not! So they need thorough inspection because of the wasps (white, black and red - the hardest to detect because they are of the same color as the fruit).

R Falk (Gateshead) recommends to

- wash the fruit
- remove the part opposite to the stem - which is where insects enter the fruit
- cut the fig in two, turn each half inside-out to expose the inside
- observe the two halves to see if there is movement - if not it can be eaten

R Vaye (Israel) recommends to

- open the fruit
- place it face down in a transparent glass of water
- if wasps come out, float then fall down in the glass, the fruit should be thrown away. If not it can be eaten.